# What is meant by `DiracDelta'[t]`?

Tags: dirac-delta, wolfram-alpha

While calculating an inverse Laplace transform Wolfram Alpha returned to me the following output:

`7 + 2 DiracDelta[-1 + t] + 14 DiracDelta[t] + HeavisideTheta[-1 + t] + 16 DiracDelta'[t]`

What does `DiracDelta'[t]` mean? A derivative of Dirac Delta function? Wouldn't that be infinite at $0$ and zero everywhere else? That is, basically the Dirac Delta function itself?

Answer (score 1):

"Infinite at zero and zero everywhere else" is a *woefully* inadequate description of the dirac delta.

The best (and usually *literal*) definition of the dirac delta is basically that the notation resembling an integral containing a dirac delta is defined to mean evaluation:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x-a) \, \mathrm{d}x := f(a) $$

whenever $f$ is continuous at $a$. Notation involving the derivative is defined by a similar formula:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta'(x-a) \, \mathrm{d}x := -f'(a) $$

where $f$ is continuously differentiable at $a$. The idea behind the definition is that it is is meant to invoke partial integration; to imagine a hypothetical calculation

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( f(x) \delta'(x-a) + f'(x) \delta(x-a) \right)  \, \mathrm{d}x = (f(x) \delta(x-a))\big|_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} = 0 $$

There is a systematic approach to this sort of stuff: they're called  [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). On a suitable space of *test functions*, this partial integration formula is the [definition of the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions).